# US Passport will expire while I'm in Grand Cayman

Tags: passports, international-travel, us-citizens, cayman-islands

Itinerary:
Leaving US to Grand Cayman May 10
Coming back May 16

My passport expires May 15, 2016.

Since weekend is upon us, can't renew passport in time.

Can I still fly to Grand Cayman, then go to U.S. Consular Agency there and get it renewed to fly back?

Answer (score 34):

The Cayman Islands require US passports to be valid for the period of intended stay, meaning if the Airline decides to double check, you won't be able to board the flight. What's more, even if you do get on you just might get sent back at the border (although border guards may choose to give leeway if it's just about one day)

Answer (score 33):

In addition to the passport validity problem Crazydre points out, you're assuming the Consular Agency there can renew your passport in a couple of days, with several of those days being on a weekend. There's no particular reason to believe they can do it so quickly. You'd also need to have passport photos and the other required documents to process your renewal, which can be difficult to arrange while you're on vacation.

The good news is that it may well still be possible to get a passport in time here in the US if you can get to a [passport agency](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/information/where-to-apply/agencies.html). You can call them 24/7 to arrange an appointment, and they can usually handle an emergency renewal if you show proof of upcoming travel. You'll need to bring a completed application form, photos, payment, etc... to the appointment.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers. Follow up on the passport agency ... is it possible to show up without an appointment and be seen? I called and their next available appointment would be too late.

Comment: I got a new U.S. passport in Bogota, which took seven days.  If you show a plane ticket that you're leaving sooner and need it to travel, they can do it in a few days.  The Cayman consular islands might rush it for you if you show that it's expiring.  Wouldn't hurt to [call them](http://kingston.usembassy.gov/service/consular-agents.html) though.

Comment: @user43226 According to the website, you need an appointment to get services at an agency. I assume you told them that you have non-refundable airline tickets to fly on the 10th and need to get in before then and they said no?

Answer (score 8):

Resolution:
Went to passport agency in LA at 5:30am (opens at 7am). Luckily they were able to take me without an appointment and received a renewed passport by 3pm the same day.

Thank you all for your feedback.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Have a great trip!

Answer (score 2):

You can request the expedited service by mail for renewing your passport. And they will renew it in 3 weeks only (instead of the 8 weeks it could take) paying $60 extra.

It will be somehow faster if you go either to a Passport Agency in person or use the services of a passport expediting company. However this option will also take more than 1 week.

You could also try to cut the trip one day short. I am not sure though whether Cayman expects the passport to be valid for some months more than the intended stay. This would be the case in many countries.

Comment: Cayman only requires US passports to be valid for the Duration of stay

Comment: @Crazydre: then, if the OP could re-book the flight maybe he could travel there anyway.